# Can't connect via FTP to LoPy L01

Tags: ftp, connection, filezilla, upload

I need to connect via FTP to my LoPy oem L01 in order to delete everything from it, since i can't upload anything due to an error during the writing process.

I'm trying to connect using FileZilla, but it seems impossible to connect to FTP server.

I followed every step from the [documentation](https://docs.pycom.io/gettingstarted/programming/ftp/), but it won't connect.

plz help I'm stucked

Answer (score 1):

I solved, just resetted the board using:

for a soft reset:

```
    >>>import sys
    >>>sys.exit()
```

for an hard reset:

```
    >>>import machine
    >>>machine.reset()
```

for a device's filesystem reset:

```
    >>>import os
    >>>os.mkfs('/flash')
```

The last one worked for me, since i think there were some corrupted file uploaded on the board.